# How should I interpret "…should exchange for one-and-twenty shillings" from Adam Smith's Wealth of Nations.?

Tags: british-english

the book talks about a Guinea exchanging for "one-and-twenty shillings".  I don't know what this means and its hard to google.

Comment: "one-and-twenty" means twentyone.

Answer (score 2):

A [guinea](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guinea_(coin)), a British coin minted from 1663 to 1814 from approximately a quarter ounce of gold, was [worth £1 and 1 shilling](http://www.telegraph.co.uk/finance/personalfinance/10416806/Guinea-sovereign-shilling-a-short-history-of-the-British-coinage.html). Since at that time there were 20 shillings to the pound, you're talking an even exchange: a guinea for one-and-twenty shillings, i.e., 21 shillings.

Comment: i don't understand.  what i am confused about specifically is the "<a> and <b>" where `a` and `b` are both numbers.  is "one and one" eleven, is it two, what is it?

Comment: @AlexBollbach [*Sing a song of sixpence, / 
A pocket full of rye. / 
**Four and twenty** blackbirds, / 
Baked in a pie. // 
When the pie was opened / 
The birds began to sing; / 
Wasn't that a dainty dish, / 
To set before the king.*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sing_a_Song_of_Sixpence)

Comment: I edited my answer to address that. English used to have the option of expressing numbers as they still do in German: four and twenty=24.